# Can I use log4j2.xml in my Apache Spark application

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

We are trying to integrate log4j2.xml instead of log4j.properties in Apache Spark application, We integrated log4j2.xml but, the problem is unable to write the worker log of the application and there is no problem for writing driver log. Can any one suggest how to integrate log4j2.xml in Apache Spark application with successful writing of both worker and driver log.

Thanks in advance..,