# Use Log4j2 in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, log4j, log4j2

I have tried (unsuccessfully so far) to replace Log4j with Log4j2 for Apache Spark Logging. So far I have managed to use Log4j2 for my application logs, but I would like to use it also for Spark internal logs (to avoid having 2 different configurations and frameworks coexisting at the same time).

Based on the *related questions*, I understand that I should somehow tell Spark to ignore it's own log4j jars and use the ones I provide with the help of SPARK_CLASSPATH.

However, I have faced 2 issues:

1. If I remove log4j jars from $SPARK_HOME/jars directory and add the new ones through SPARK_CLASSPATH, the driver won't start, complaining about missing log4j.
2. If I leave log4j jars in $SPARK_HOME/jars directory but tell spark-submit to use jars located on another directory (using --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath), the application will immediately fail with a StackOverflowError, similar to what is mentioned [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2646).

I hope someone can shed some light into my issue.

Regards

Related questions: [Using log4j2 in Spark java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42496654/using-log4j2-in-spark-java-application) , [Can I use log4j2.xml in my Apache Spark application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37966044/can-i-use-log4j2-xml-in-my-apache-spark-application) , [Configuring Apache Spark Logging with Scala and logback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42356887/configuring-apache-spark-logging-with-scala-and-logback)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't use log4j 2 since spark is hardcoded with log4j 1.

The best solution I found was to just use log4j 1 so I can also collect spark logs as well as my own.